# Android RecyclerView LayoutOrientation not working

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

So I've spent the last few hours trying to create a horizontal scrolling `Recyclerview`.
I'm pretty sure that I'm following the correct techniques for setting the `LayoutManager` for the `Recyclerview`, but it just won't work. on the preview it works, but once I push it to the Emulator, it still renders the list in vertical mode instead of horizontal.

I haven't made any references/changes to the `Recyclerview` programmatically (I tried setting the `LayoutManager` before, but it also didn't work).

Screenshot showing the issue:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try adding this code to your java class in the onCreate Method

```
   mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));//set your recyclerview layout to hoizontal
```

also try posting your java or kotlin code next time to get better feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `Layoutmanager` from fragment/activity. If you are using Kotlin, do this

**XML**

```
       <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

**Fragment/Activity**

```
    val layout = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
    recycler.layoutManager = layout
```

*Change `this` with `requireContext()` if in fragment